# Haskell, returning String while using IO Integer to compute that string

Tags: string, haskell, io, xmonad

Today I ran into the following problem:

I can read the current screen resolution in Haskell using Xlib-bindings using a function called getScreenWidth (--> I get an IO Integer). This is working so far.

Now I want to use that value as a label for a plugin of my desktop environment (xmonad). The plugin infrastructure only allows a function mapping a "WorkspaceId" (which basically is an integer) to a String.

```
...
-- Constructor for PrettyPrint: 
ppCurrent :: WorkspaceId -> String
...
```

Currently I am using my own function to map an ID to a String, which is working:

```
myPPCurrent :: WorkspaceId -> String
myPPCurrent x = "Desktop: " ++ show x
```

The output is as expected "Desktop: 1" (or whatever ID i am on).

Now I want it to be "Desktop: 1 (1680px)" where 1680 equals the return value of getScreenWidth.

**My Problem:** getScreenWidth returns IO Integer, so I can not simply use,

```
myPPCurrent x = do
    y <- getScreenWidth
    return "Desktop: " ++ show x ++ show y
```

since i the return type isn't String. Google told me, that I can not convert "IO Integer" to "Integer" in Haskell, so I really have no clue, how I can keep the prototype/constructor (however Haskell calls it) "WorkspaceId -> String" while using an "IO Integer" to generate that String.

Is that even possible at all? If so, how?

Comment: You need to stay within the monad.

Answer (score 4):

I've never used XMonad: I'm basing this answer on general Haskell knowledge and what I've found on the internet in 2½minutes.

Anyway, I'm assuming somewhere you have a `main` that calls `xmonad`.

```
main = xmonad myConfig
```

Or maybe

```
main = xmonad XConfig {
          normalBorderColor = "#8080ff",
          -- etc
```

Or whatever. Let's look at the types.

```
main :: IO ()
xmonad :: (LayoutClass l Window, Read (l Window)) => XConfig l -> IO ()
myConfig :: XConfig l -- whatever type `l` is
```

Now suppose instead of `myConfig`, we have

```
makeMyConfig :: IO (XConfig l) -- I still don't know what `l` is
```

`makeMyConfig` isn't a configuration --- it's something that will make a configuration at runtime, potentially depending on files from disk, or the time, or the screen resolution.... You use it like so:

```
main = do
    config <- makeMyConfig
    xmonad config
```

And the point is that because the `XConfig l` we're using now is derived from an `IO (XConfig l)`, it can incorporate `String`s derived from `IO String`s and `Integer`s derived from `IO Integer`s, etc. So that's your in for using `getScreenWidth` in your configuration.

Answer (score 3):

You can't leave the IO monad once you're in it, so you'll need to return an `IO String` instead of a `String` e.g.

```
myPPCurrent :: WorkspaceId -> Integer -> String
myPPCurrent x = "Desktop: " ++ show x ++ show y

getWorkspaceName :: WorkspaceId -> IO String
getWorkspaceName id = do
    w <- getScreenWidth
    return $ myPPCurrent id w
```